# Proper way to work with wpdb to get user's firstname

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I want to use $wpdb to get user's firstname. I know how to do it with php and mysql query, but I want to use $wpdb.

The problem is that I don't know how to use it. I tried to create simple 
query to display user fist_name by user_id and than echo it. This is what I ended up with:

```
$mywpdb1 = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT first_name 
        FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
        WHERE user_id = 2", 
        $user->first_name
    ) 
); 
echo $mywpdb1;
```

Comment: I see you are using `$user->first_name`. If you have a `$user` object, `$user->first_name` already contains the first name field. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You should'nt really be using wp query here, use [get_user_meta();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Example:

```
$first_name = get_user_meta(2, 'first_name', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a direct database query for `first_name` meta field the correct way is:

```
global $wpdb;

$user_id = 2;
$meta_key = "first_name";

$first_name = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT meta_value 
        FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
        WHERE user_id = %d 
        AND meta_key = %s",
        $user_id,
        $meta_key
    ) 
);

echo $first_name;
```

But I think it is better to use the `WP_User` object, which contains the `first_name` meta field as a public property:

```
// Get the user with ID = 2
$user = new WP_User( 2 );

// Grab de the first_name
$first_name = $user->first_name;
```

You can use `get_user_meta()` function also, as suggested by @PaulH:

```
$first_name = get_user_meta(2, 'first_name', true);
```

But I thhink `WP_User` object is better than `get_user_meta()` for this specific case for these main reasons:

1. Usually, when working with users you have to load the user object anyway. For example, in the description of question the user object is already loaded, so **there is no need for anything else**, just use `$user->first_name`.
2. I don't think there is a huge perfomance difference between both methods but looking how `get_user_meta()` works ([at the end it uses this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_meta_cache/)), it loads all user meta fields, even if you only want one field. That may have a worst perfomance than loading a `WP_User` object in some situations.

Comment: Why would you load the entire user object if you only need the first_name? Performance-wise using `get_user_meta` is superior.

Comment: I've updated the answer explaining why I think it is better to use user object in this specific case. Are you sure the performance is better using `get_user_meta()`? I don't think so for this case.